# Find a letter (from an Array) in and Array and then use the index to get a value from another Array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to evaluate a word using the calc function below
lets assume that showLetters = ["S","W","I","F","T"]

So S = 1, W = 4, I = 1, F = 4, T = 1 and give me a wordScore of 11....

I use the array alphaLetter to find the position of the letter in the alphabet.
I use the index of the found letter to get its value from alphaScore.

```
 func calcButton() {
    var testWord = ""
    var wordScore = 0

    let alphaLetter = Array("A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z")
    let alphaScore = Array ("1,3,2,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10")

    for k in (0...6)
    {
      testWord = testWord + showLetters[k]

      let letterFound = String(showLetters[k])
      *if let index = alphaLetter.firstIndex(of: letterFound) {*

    }


     }
```

I am struggling to get the index

I tried assigning letterFound as a string of the found letter,. and then tried to use 
if let index = alphaLetter.firstIndex(of: letterFound)

but that gives me an error
Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

So I am a little bit stuck...

Suggestion or guidance would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Are you aware that your arrays `alphaLetter` and `alphaScore` have commas as elements? So the elements of your first array are "A" then comma then "B" then comma and so on. For example "C" is the fifth element, not the third element. Is that really what you want? — Also, the elements are Characters, not Strings. Is that also what you want?

Comment: Ahh, that may explain some things.. I just need to find the value for each letter, so not 100% sure of the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alphaLetter` and `alphaScore` are strings. The result of creating an array from one string is `[Character]` including the commas!.

Probably you mean this (tested in a Playground)

```
let showLetters = ["S","W","I","F","T"]

func calcButton() {
    var testWord = ""
    var wordScore = 0

    let alphaLetter = Array(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"])
    let alphaScore = Array ([1,3,2,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10])

    for k in 0..<showLetters.count 
    {
        testWord = testWord + showLetters[k]

        let letterFound = showLetters[k]
        if let index = alphaLetter.firstIndex(of: letterFound) {
            wordScore += alphaScore[index]
        }
    }
    print(wordScore)
}

calcButton()
```

Nevertheless it's much more efficient to use a dictionary `["A" : 1, "B" : 3 ...]`

```
func calcButton() {
    var testWord = ""
    var wordScore = 0

    let alphaDict =  ["P": 3, "U": 1, "B": 3, "M": 3, "A": 1, "C": 2, "V": 4, "L": 1, "Q": 10, "D": 2, "H": 4, "K": 5, "N": 1, "J": 8, "T": 1, "E": 1, "X": 8, "R": 1, "O": 1, "I": 1, "G": 2, "F": 4, "Y": 4, "Z": 10, "W": 4, "S": 1]

    for character in showLetters {
        if let value = alphaDict[character] {
            wordScore += value
        }
    }
    print(wordScore)
}
```

Comment: The code above gives me the same error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')" I will take a look at Dictionaries though, as not aware of them.